# passing arguments from aspx pase to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function, arguments

i have a function with an argument in javascript that looks like this:

```
function editRow(str){
var row= document.getElementById(str);
var cols = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
..........
}
```

and the function should get an id of some tr, and to replace all the text in the td's that this tr include.

so, i tried to add a button in the tr that i want to change and with 'onclick' to call the function, but the problem is that the function working only without the argument, if im trying to send an argument its not working...
the aspx.cs page:

```
......
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)

{
(....more not important code.....)

allStr +=

"<td><input type='button' **onclick='editRow('row"+row["Id"]+"');'** value='edit'><form id='TreeDelete2' action='delete.aspx' method='post' onsubmit='return IfToDelete();'><input type='image' name='sbmt' src='/images/X.gif'/></form></td></tr>";

}

......
```

i marked the event with **.

the id of the tr that i want to change is row1 (row["Id"]==1)

so there is some other way to pass the argument from the aspx file? or i did somthing wrong?

Comment: Is click event triggered by this method?

Answer (score 0):

Change your js function to get the `tr element itself`,

```
function editRow(row){
   //var row= document.getElementById(str);
   var cols = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
   ..........
}
```

And `input button string` from code behind (not sure why you are doing this in the code behind),

```
"<td><input type='button' " +
        "onclick='editRow(this.parentNode.parentNode);' value='edit'>" + 
     "...</td>"
```

Comment: There is a way to thank which is up voting and/or accepting the answer. That is how stackoverflow works.